# auto closing li when cliclking another li in a jquery accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am making this accordion which has ul li's inside li.I want to automatic close all open li's when click on a single li.So far i have done this.The problem with it  that when i click one li ,i have to click it again to close it before opening another one.I just want to autoclose every opened li before opening another one.Don't know how to do it.please someone help me making this...

HTML code

```
      <div class="main-menu">
                            <ul class="1st_menu">
                                <li><a href="#"><span>D'MAIRE ACCOUNT</span></a>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu" id="info_list1">
                                        <li class="has_par"><a href="#" class="show_par icon_plus">Widgets</a>
                                            <p style="display:none" class="par_desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="has_par"><a href="#" class="show_par icon_plus">Menus</a>
                                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod t</p>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="has_par"><a href="#" class="show_par icon_plus">Products</a>
                                            <p>quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>


    </li>
</ul>
    </div>
```

jquery code

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
  var $li_p = $('ul[class="sub-menu"] li').children('p');
  var $li_a = $('ul[class="sub-menu"] li').children('a');
  if($li_p.slideToggle().toggleClass('closed')){
    $li_p.hide();
  }
    $('ul[class="sub-menu"] li').click(function() {
     var ullist = $(this).children('p:first');
     ullist.slideToggle().toggleClass('closed');
     var isVisible = ullist.is(".closed");
     var img_icon = $(this).children('a');
     if (isVisible === true){
          img_icon.removeClass('icon_minus').addClass('icon_plus');
      } else {
          img_icon.removeClass('icon_plus').addClass('icon_minus');
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jquery siblings method to grab all of the adjacent li tags and then loop over them to check to see if they are open. If they are open, you can then close them and remove the minus class and add the plus class.

```
var siblings = $(this).siblings('li');
$.each(siblings, function (i, key) {
    if ($(key).find('a').hasClass('icon_minus')) {         
        var sibling = $(key).children('p:first');
        $(sibling).slideToggle().addClass('closed');
      $(key).find('a').removeClass('icon_minus').addClass('icon_plus');
    }
});
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/086zuboc/

Answer (score 1):

Exclude the current element with .not(this)

Try something like this:

```
$('ul[class="sub-menu"] li').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.li').not(this).addClass('closed');
  $(this).toggleClass('closed');
}
```

Comment: sorry not getting you .i want to toggle .sub-menu li's auto close not parent ones @tom

Comment: I forgot a .find('.li'). The idea is to find all li's inside the parent ul except the clicked one and close them. Then open the one you clicked.