# how does the dropdown open alternately?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I made a dropdown that has submenus. I have a problem I'm facing. What I want, when I open the 'Investor Relations' menu, another dropdown menu closes. When I open the 'Tata Kelola' menu, the investor menu that I opened earlier automatically closes. So I only want 1 dropdown menu to open.

However, I still have a problem like the picture below. the menu is still all open, not open alternately.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nouVz.png)

**My HTML Code**

```
    <div id="slide-menu">
        <ul class="main">
            <li>
                <a href="<?= base_url() . '/bisnis-hotel' ?>">Bisnis</a>
            </li>
            <li class="has-child">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Investor Relations</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?= base_url(); ?>investor-relations/laporan-keuangan">Laporan Keuangan</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?= base_url(); ?>investor-relations/annual-report">Annual Report</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?= base_url(); ?>investor-relations/rups">RUPS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?= base_url(); ?>investor-relations/surat-kuasa">Surat Kuasa</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="has-child">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Tata Kelola</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?= base_url(); ?>tata-kelola/organisasi">Tata Kelola Perusahaan</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?= base_url(); ?>komite">Komite</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?= base_url(); ?>tanggung-jawab-perusahaan">Tanggung Jawab Perusahaan</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="has-child">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Perusahaan</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?= base_url(); ?>milestone">Milestone</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?= base_url(); ?>vision-mision">Vision & Mision</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?= base_url(); ?>dewan-komisaris">Dewan Komisaris</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?= base_url(); ?>dewan-direksi">Dewan Direksi</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?= base_url(); ?>karir">Karir</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="<?= base_url(); ?>press-release">Berita</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="<?= base_url(); ?>karir">Karir</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="slide-footer-wrapper">
            <div class="footer-menu-wrapper">
                <ul id="footer-menu">
                    <li><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>contactus">Hubungi Kami | </a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>tnc">Term & Conditions | </a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="social-menu-wrapper">
                <ul id="slide-menu-social">
                    <li class="label">
                        Follow us:
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">
                            <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/main/instagram-logo.svg') ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">
                            <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/main/facebook-logo.svg') ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/main/twitter-logo.svg') ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**My JS Code**

```
       $("#slide-menu li.has-child").on('click', function() {
            toggleSubMenu(this);
        });

        function toggleSubMenu(parent_menu) {
            // submenu height
            let submenu = $(parent_menu).find(".submenu").height();

            // normal parent menu height
            let height = $(parent_menu).height();

            // init variabel new_height
            let new_height = 0;

            if ($(parent_menu).hasClass("active")) {
                $(parent_menu).removeClass("active");

                // ketika ditutup kurangi tinggi parent dengan tinggi sumbenu
                new_height = height - submenu;
            } else {
                $(parent_menu).addClass("active");

                // ketika dibuka tambahkan tinggi parent dengan tinggi sumbenu
                new_height = height + submenu;
            }

            // Set tinggi parent menu
            $(parent_menu).css("height", new_height);
        }
```

**My CSS**

```
    div#slide-menu {
        position: fixed;
        right: 0px;
        padding-right: 25px;
        height: 100vh;
        background: rgb(38, 69, 53);
        width: 95%;
        text-align: right;
        padding-top: 78px;
        z-index: 100;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: ease transform 0.3s;
    }

    #slide-menu .main {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        height: 70%;
    }

    div#slide-menu a {
        color: white;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family: 'Brandon Grotesque';
        line-height: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    div#slide-menu ul {
        list-style: none;
    }

    div#slide-menu li.has-child::after {
        content: '';
        border-top: 3px solid white;
        border-right: 3px solid white;
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 22px;
        right: 5px;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        transition: ease transform 0.2s;
    }

    div#slide-menu li.has-child {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 45px;
        transition: ease all 0.2s;
    }

    div#slide-menu ul.main .submenu a {
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 35px;
        font-family: 'Brandon Grotesque Light';
    }

    z div#slide-menu ul.submenu {
        height: 0px;
        display: block;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    div#slide-menu>ul>li {
        padding-right: 50px;
        margin: 30px 0px;
        position: relative;
    }

    div#slide-menu li.has-child.active>a {
        color: #c9a87e;
        font-family: 'Brandon Grotesque';
        font-weight: 700;
        /* font-family: 'Brandon Grotesque Bold'; */
    }

    div#slide-menu li.has-child.active::after {
        content: '';
        border-top-color: #c9a87e;
        border-right-color: #c9a87e;
        transform: rotate(135deg);
    }

    div#slide-menu.show {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }

    header #slide-menu-layer {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        background: transparent;
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to use an accordion. Check this out - https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Any fiddle or codepen you work with it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [auto closing li when cliclking another li in a jquery accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490162/auto-closing-li-when-cliclking-another-li-in-a-jquery-accordion)

Comment: i dont want using accordion for this menu @karansharma

Comment: can you give me how to use that with my code above, please? @Michel

Comment: no, i dont have @Rafv

Comment: @frankfurt please provide ur css, im going to check it

Comment: i've edited post above, please check the code @Rafv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check earlier menu and make sure it's currently close. If it opened, force them to close the menu. Here's working fiddle:

```js
// Capture initial height of parent menu
const menuHasChild = $("#slide-menu .has-child");
const menuAnchor = $(".has-child > a");
const menuHeight = menuHasChild.height();

// Since you would probably change the height
// over the css, apply initial height to dom
menuHasChild.css("height", menuHeight);

/**
 * Open current menu and check if earlier
 * menu was active, if so, close them.
 * @param {Event.currentTarget} target
 */
function openSubMenu(target) {
  $(target).addClass("active");
  $(target).css("height", target.scrollHeight);
  
  resetEarlierActive(target);
};

/**
 * Close current active menu.
 * @param {Event.currentTarget} target
 */
function closeSubMenu(target) {
  $(target).removeClass("active");
  $(target).css("height", menuHeight);
};

/**
 * Check and reset earlier active menu
 * @param {Event.currentTarget} target
 */
function resetEarlierActive(target) {
    $(menuHasChild).each(function(index, child) {
    if (child !== $(target).get(0)) {
        return closeSubMenu(child);
    }
  });
}
/**
 * Toggle current target submenu.
 * @param {Event} event Menu click handler
 */
function toggleSubMenu(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent Anchor
  
    const currentTarget = $(event.target).parent()[0];
  const currentlyOff = !$(currentTarget).hasClass("active");
  const currentlyOn = $(currentTarget).hasClass("active");
  
  if (currentlyOff) openSubMenu(currentTarget);
  if (currentlyOn) closeSubMenu(currentTarget);
}

// Release it
menuAnchor.on('click', toggleSubMenu);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
}

ul, ol { list-style: none; }

.main li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 25px;
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="slide-menu">
  <ul class="main">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Bisnis</a>
    </li>
    <li class="has-child">
        <a href="#">Investor Relations</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Laporan Keuangan</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Annual Report</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">RUPS</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Surat Kuasa</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-child">
        <a href="#">Tata Kelola</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Tata Kelola Perusahaan</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Komite</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Tanggung Jawab Perusahaan</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-child">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Perusahaan</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Milestone</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Vision & Mision</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Dewan Komisaris</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Dewan Direksi</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Karir</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Berita</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Karir</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I've been discover your code before you update the question. Im just adding a little css to help, you can override it. Please tell me how's going next. Thanks!

Terima kasih!

Comment: @frankfurt sama sama bro! :)